# A question of Adams-Bashforth formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

This problem is from Numerical Analysis 3th (David Kincaid & Ward Cheney) problem 8.4.8

> a. Using the method of undetermined coefficients, determine A and B in the following Adams-Bashforth formula.(Do not change to a corresponding numerical integration formula)
>   $$
> x_{n+1}=x_n+h[Af_n+Bf_{n-1}]
> $$
>   b. Repeat Part a by changing it to a corresponding numerical integration formula.

---

I am confused the difference between a and b. I only know integrates $1$ and $t$ to solve A and B by undetermined coefficients.

Comment: Quite strange, the integration formula has to be applied to interval $[t_n, t_{n+1}]$, but use the values on interval $[t_{n-1}, t_{n}]$. Obviously, you can construct one using undeterminced coefficients. The other way is to construct the formula by integrating the lagrange interpolating polynomial for $p(t) = f(t, x(t))$. But that is exatly the idea of constructing the method.